# File IO very slow on RHEL6

Tags: rhel

I recently moved to RHEL6 santaigo OS. I am finding the file io operations like copy, file download taking a long time. This was not the case when I have used RHEL5 earlier. Could anyone suggest a possible way to troubleshoot the issue. The file system has two mounted devices.

1. /dev/mapper/*********
2. /dev/sda1

Both are ext4 type.

Comment: Check `dmesg` for any error messages related to the filesystem or partition devices.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use `strace`, at least initially to start diagnosing an issue such as this.

```
$ strace -o some.log ..copy command...
```

You can then analyze the log, `some.log` to see if the copy command is getting hung up on a particular resource not being there.

You can also use a tool such as `iostat` to watch the performance between your storage devices as data is read/wrtiten to them.

#### Example

```
$ iostat 2
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
          23.46    0.00    2.26    1.38    0.00   72.90

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
sda               6.50         0.00       220.00          0        440
dm-0              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-1              3.00         0.00        10.00          0         20
dm-2             16.00         0.00       210.00          0        420
dm-3              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-4              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-5              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-6              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-7              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-8              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-9              0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
dm-10             0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
```

You can narrow the focus of that tool to a specific device as well.